# Android version jelly bean

Tags: android

I have made an android app and uploaded the same on playstore. When i try to download it from playstore it is available for all android version accept jelly bean. It shows it is not compatible with your device. Can somebody help me with that?

My manifest file :

```
        <supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />


<!--GCM Permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.indianmarketview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
android:name="com.indianmarketview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />


<!--GCM Permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.indianmarketview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
android:name="com.indianmarketview.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: Your app's manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Make sure you have set the correct permissions as well as min/target API levels correctly. Without seeing your manifest file, this is all I can offer.

As a side note, when you upload your app to the play store it gives you a list of compatible devices (out of 11k or around that). You could check if your device is on there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i am not getting which permission is wrong. Here is my manifest file please let me know?

Comment: 1st, remove duplicated code. (You've posted it twice). 
Also, can you provide the **full** manifest. Just the permissions may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the android:minSdkVersion="int"
as per your requirement &
android:targetSdkVersion="int"
and try target sdk version should be latest in which your app will targeting. 
And remove unused permissions and other declarations.

Comment: thanks for your response . i have already done that.  minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23